# How do I get a document ID from Firestore and use it in a Realtime Database path?

Tags: android, firebase, reference, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a "like" button that works like this: when the user clicks the like button, I'll use the user id to add a like value in my Realtime database. My project also uses Firestore and I want to use the data there to construct a path to a new "like" in the Realtime Database.

Here's how I get my document id from Firestore to later build a Realtime Database path.

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
 FirebaseUser currentUser;
 private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference LikesRef;


int CountLike;
private String currentUserI;
Boolean cheker = false;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anu_detals);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserI = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

       final String PostKey = db.collection("Anu").document().getId();


       LikesRef = FirebaseDatabase. getInstance().getReference().child("Like");
```

Here is the button to add a like. If the person click again, I'll remove the `currentuser` from the database and count as a "dislike".

```
 bt_like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        cheker = true;
        LikesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (cheker.equals(true)) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(PostKey).hasChild(currentUserI)) {
                        LikesRef.child(PostKey).child(currentUserI).removeValue();
                        likecheker = false;
                    }
                    else
                        {
                        LikesRef.child(PostKey).child(currentUserI).setValue(true);
                        cheker = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }

});
```

I'm not getting any errors, but the data (Document id and currentuser) is not going to the Realtime Database. How can I get a Reference/id from Firestore to use in the Realtime Database?

[Data in Realtime Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btj9E.png)

[Data in Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqDvD.png)

Comment: First step would be to stop ignoring errors and implement `onCancelled`. The simplest version is: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: What does `databaseError.toException()` return? Please also responde with @

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i just add it, now my app crash and show this error "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied"

Comment: @AlexMamo so far nothing, do i have to add something?

Comment: @Luis This error: `"com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied"` tells you exactly what you need to do. Just change the permissions so you can rad/write the database.

Comment: @AlexMamo i just did it, and now it it's working but instead of get the document it and store the 'currentuserid there, it's creating a new 'collection id' and add the  user each time a click on it. Look on the edit so you can understand better.

Comment: Is the like button associated with a specific post? As you said, right now you're creating a new PostKey document each time.

Comment: Yea. For example it's like a store product rating. Each product is on a post and each post has a like button. Each post has already a document Id created automatically. So, once a user click on the link button its id will be send to a new collection. This new collection will get the documentsnapshot id and inside each documentsnapshot id will be stored all the Id of user who clicked there. @JRLtechwriting

Comment: Then you might want to re-use the document ID of the post in the PostKey, `PostKey = db.collection("Anu").document(ProductIDVar)`.

Comment: @JRLtechwriting Do I need to do it to each ID?

Comment: Yes, if you want a like button for each post. Are you showing the "like" button on the same screen where you show the post?

Comment: The like bottom is inside de post screen @JRLtechwriting. On firebase we can use 'PostKe = getRef(). getKey.' Can't I use a similar on Firestone?

Comment: You already know what the PostID is, right? Don't you use it to populate the post screen, something like `db.collection("Anu").document(PostID).get()`. Can you re-use that PostID variable?

Comment: Yea. but it's many documents i can't do it to all of them. The best option would get the id as a string then add on another code