# How to get DocumentSnapshot id as String?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

How can i get the id of a document in Firestore?

```
final String PostKey = db.collection("Anuncio").document().getId();
```

I'm trying on this way, but it return a new id. How can get de id of the a document that already exit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the document ID before hand, you can [retrieve all the documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) and print out the IDs:

```
db.collection("Anuncio")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

If you're interested in a subset of the documents, you can [add a query clause](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) to filter the documents:

```
db.collection("Anuncio")
        .whereEqualTo("some-field", "some-value")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Actually it isn't what i want yet. I want to turn the documentSnaphot id on a String so i can save it on another collection @JRLtechwriting. It would be like getting the Key on Firebase

Comment: Sure, just need more context. Do you already know the doc ID of the document? Or do you know of a unique field value it contains?

Comment: Yea. You code Works good. i think i just could explain well. Look my post and check if you can understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897811/is-it-possible-to-get-document-id-from-firestore-and-send-to-firebase-real-time?noredirect=1#comment96588605_54897811